# WPF Edit Template -> Edit a Copy

Tags: wpf, templates

---

1.pic -->> https://i.hizliresim.com/lbAopX.jpg

---

I was watching a tutorial about WPF Control Template and he is right click a button on the UI then Edit Template -> Edit a Copy , finally result is here (First Picture.)

---

2.pic -->> https://i.hizliresim.com/o6JLm9.jpg

---

In the second picture , I wanted to make the same thing but my result is different and some triggers none (IsPressed,IsMouseOver etc.). Why my result is different ? I searched on the internet but i did not find it.
Could you help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: No one to help ?